# CakePHP 2.x How to call a helper in a foreach in a View?

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach, rendering, view-helpers

Here's my situation put into generalized terms:

CakePHP 2.x

I have a Model called `SalesLog` that holds `user_id`, `sale_id`, `action`, and `description`.

The `SalesLogs` index shows the list of logs (Offers some filters).

The `View` code currently runs an if statement to decide which `label class` to use when rendering the `action`value.

But, this kind of rendering happens in many places throughout the app. Each time, whatever `View` it is runs its own if statement.

I am trying to take this decision away from the `Views` and put it into one centralized place, so that whenever any `View` needs to render `action`, they can just call on this place and get the answer.

I came across CakePHP 2.x `Helpers` and have successfully created my `ActionLabelHelper.php`.

The problem now is that the `index` `View` lists the logs with a `foreach` statement and when I call the method in the foreach, it says I can't do that to a non-object.

```
// Just a shortened example here:
<?php foreach($SalesLogs as $sl) { ?>
      <tr>
          <td> <?= $sl['SalesLog']['user_id']; ?> </td>
          <td> <?= $sl->ActionLabel->actionLabel($sl['SalesLog']['action']); ?> </td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

If I call it like this (Based on what the documentation shows):

`<?= $this->ActionLabel->actionLabel($sl['SalesLog']['action']); ?>`

The `View` shows the list with all of the right `actions`, but they all get labeled based on whatever the first log's `action` was.

Any ideas on how to adjust the call and/or places where this method should be in order for this to work?

I also work with `Rails`, which made me want to create a `partial` for `action`, but it seemed silly to have a `partial` for one field and it doesn't look like CakePHP works with those as naturally as `Rails` does.

What do you guys have for me?

**Helper Code:**

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class ActionLabelHelper extends AppHelper {

public function actionLabel($action)
{
  switch ($action) {
    case 'inserted':        
        $type = 'primary';
    case 'removed':
        $type = 'danger';
    case 'changed':
        $type = 'warning';
    default:
        $type = 'warning';
    }
    return "<span class='label label-" . $type . "'>" . $action . "</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: <?= $this->ActionLabel->actionLabel($sl['SalesLog']['action']); ?> should work.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, it did work, but my `switch` didn't have the `break` after each thing. I've put them in and now it's perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, calling the Helper function like this, since the Helper is a property of the View – not the Model:

```
<?= $this->ActionLabel->actionLabel($sl['SalesLog']['action']); ?>
```

If this does not output the expected result, I would recommend to `debug($action);` inside the `actionLabel` method to see if the right stuff goes in, in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. After looking closely, the issue was in the `switch`. I needed to `break` out of each case. Now it's working exactly as it should.